# Formatting a phone number in SSRS - within a very concatenated statement

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, reporting-services, concatenation, mask

I have two pieces of code

```
 ="GROUP ESCORT:" & " " & CHR(10) & 
IIf(First(Fields!leader_lname.Value, "DataSet1") = First(Fields!grp_escort_name.Value, "DataSet1"), 
                                                   First(Fields!grp_escort_name.Value, "DataSet1"),
                                                  (First(Fields!grp_escort_name.Value, "DataSet1") & " " & CHR(10) & IIF((IsNothing(First(Fields!grp_escort_email.Value, "DataSet1"))), 
                                                                                                                                   First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1"), 
                                                                                                                                 ((First(Fields!grp_escort_email.Value, "DataSet1")) & " " & CHR(10) & First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")))))
```

a very complex nested statement that says - if  leader name is the same as escort name then simply print the escort name otherwise print the escort name, and then evaluate if email is empty print phone only -- if email isn't empty print email and phone, etc.

Now I had put together a piece of code (with the help of other codes on stack overflow to evaluate and format the phone number.

both peices of code work great independently but I've tried combinging and can't get them to work together.

```
IIF(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1") Is Nothing, Nothing, 
IIF(IsNumeric(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")), 
    Format(Val(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")), "(###) ###-####"), 
    First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")))
```

I would like the top logic to remain but the phone number if printed to be replaced by the formatted piece.

Comment: What is the error or unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to handle some of that logic in SQL with a CASE statement because it will be more concise and easy to test. But, since you're trying to get answer in SSRS so here you go.

When I have to put together a complex statement like this, I use a text editor to pull out common strings and replace them with simpler strings. For example:

1. Pull out the various values and create placeholders:

   ```
   LNAME = First(Fields!leader_lname.Value, "DataSet1")
   ENAME = First(Fields!grp_ENAME.Value, "DataSet1")
   THE_EMAIL = First(Fields!grp_escort_email.Value, "DataSet1")
   THE_PHONE = First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")
   ```
2. Then replace values in your original logic with your placeholders:

   ```
   ="GROUP ESCORT:" & " " & CHR(10) & 
   IIf ( LNAME = ENAME, 
               ENAME,
               ENAME & " " & CHR(10) & IIF(IsNothing(THE_EMAIL), THE_PHONE, (THE_EMAIL & " " & CHR(10) & THE_PHONE))
       )
   ```

This should make things easier to read. For example, you had several extra sets of ( and ).

3. You then only need to make your value changes in one place. In this case,  replace THE_PHONE with your logic:

   ```
   THE_PHONE = IIF(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1") Is Nothing, Nothing, IIF(IsNumeric(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")), Format(Val(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")), "(###) ###-####"), First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")))
   ```
4. Using your Search & Replace fuctions to put your place holders back and you get:

   ```
   ="GROUP ESCORT:" & " " & CHR(10) & 
   IIf ( First(Fields!leader_lname.Value, "DataSet1") = First(Fields!grp_ENAME.Value, "DataSet1"), 
               First(Fields!grp_ENAME.Value, "DataSet1"),
               First(Fields!grp_ENAME.Value, "DataSet1") & " " & CHR(10) & IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!grp_escort_email.Value, "DataSet1")), IIF(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1") Is Nothing, Nothing, IIF(IsNumeric(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")), Format(Val(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")), "(###) ###-####"), First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1"))), (First(Fields!grp_escort_email.Value, "DataSet1") & " " & CHR(10) & IIF(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1") Is Nothing, Nothing, IIF(IsNumeric(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")), Format(Val(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")), "(###) ###-####"), First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")))))
       )
   ```

I cannot test this, but even if the final output is wrong, hopefully the process will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This should be strait forward just replace the section with the phone number -- with the string with the formatted version.

```
="GROUP ESCORT:" & " " & CHR(10) & 
IIf(First(Fields!leader_lname.Value, "DataSet1") = First(Fields!grp_escort_name.Value, "DataSet1"), 
                                                   First(Fields!grp_escort_name.Value, "DataSet1"),
                                                  (First(Fields!grp_escort_name.Value, "DataSet1") & " " & CHR(10) & IIF((IsNothing(First(Fields!grp_escort_email.Value, "DataSet1"))), 
                                                                                                                                   (Format(Val(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")), "(###) ###-####")), 
                                                                                                                                 ((First(Fields!grp_escort_email.Value, "DataSet1")) & " " & CHR(10) & (Format(Val(First(Fields!grp_escort_phone.Value, "DataSet1")), "(###) ###-####"))))))
```